# How to know the character table of the twisted group algebra of the symmetric group $S_4$

Tags: algebraic-groups, character-theory

Given the character table of its Schur cover group, is there a way to obtain the character table of twisted group algebra from that? I am particularly interested in the symmetric group $S_4$.

Comment: First time here to ask questions, if there is anything I did not make clear, I can add.

Comment: Note that S4 has two non-isomorphic double covers.

Comment: Yes, but now that I know the character table of one of its Schur covering groups, how does that help me to find the character table  of the twisted group algebra $S_4$?